# A/C electric, heater gas

Tags: hvac

I have my A/C set to 82, by 3pm or later temp is 88-89. Does having the pilot lit on heater cause A/C to not work properly?

Comment: It's doubtful that a pilot light would generate enough heat to raise the temperature of your apartment by any noticeable amount.

Comment: Is your air conditioner running? Does the airflow feel appropriately cool?

Comment: Yes, it's running non stop, after about 11:00am, just bought house, know that the air handler is from 1985, not sure of the a/c

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not.  Merely having the pilot light on doesn't make enough heat to overheat a house.

Your cooling problem is probably

a) Problems with the A/C unit, e.g. low refrigerant or clogged condenser.

b) hot weather beyond the design basis of the system

c) a design basis that's too small for your tastes

d) something you are doing that's making a lot of heat.  E.g. cooking, baking, running a clothes dryer, printing on a laser printer, running a gaming PC, etc.

---

How do we test these things?

a) A/C problems: have the unit inspected.

b) Extremely hot weather: check the weather history.

c) Too small for home:  Have someone evaluate the size of the A/C that your home *should* have, preferably without seeing the unit you have now, as that could bias their recommendation.

I myself prefer units "on the large side" - that way I am free to turn it off when I'm away, without worrying about it struggling to catch up when I do turn it on.  Turning it off when you're away saves a lot of energy, though many people will not admit it.

d).  Other loads: Most are electric.  Find the electric meter.  There will be a spinning disc which changes speed based on your usage -- or a digital equivalent, that you may have to push a button or wait a few seconds to see.  Learn how to read this momentary rate of usage.  When the A/C is straining, run out and check its speed.  Then turn off the A/C and check it again.  **It should nearly stop.**  If it's still moving at a good clip, you are making heat inside your house, which is obviously fighting the A/C.

Comment: Had A/C company here and he told me it was the pilot light. You are the 5th person to tell me no....  He did check the refrigerant, said it was fine.  Do live in Fl and it's been miserable.  Only clothes dryer few times a wk, probably need new unit?  Air handler is from 1985, not sure of a/c unit can't read it

Comment: Old enough for the markings to be gone?   Good chance that unit is not very efficient.  You could save the cost of a new unit in a few years.  That would also give you an opportunity to upsize, relocate the evaporator to the shady side of the house, or even consider a ground-sourced system (which is cheaper to run because it's interchanging with 60F water instead of 100F-in-the-shade air.)